# DNS rewrite in asp.net or DNS redirection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page with some HTML tags

Example

Actual url

```html
<img src="https://google.com/fp/clear.png?latitude=<latitude>&amp;longitude=<longitude> alt="">
```

How do i change the domain name (google.com) to a local URL (localgoog.com), and configure  web server to redirect the URL (localgoo.com) to actual url (google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're referring to an aspx page, I'm assuming you're running on IIS. In that case, you may install the URLRewrite module into your IIS server. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then, within IIS management console, you may setup a rewrite rule to redirect any url coming in with the hostname of "localgoo.com" to "google.com". Once you save this rule, your web.config file will be modified to include the XML version of your rewrite rule, which then makes your app portable to other servers as well.

```
   <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectToGoogle" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^localgoo.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="//google.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

The {R:0} is a captured group of anything that comes after the hostname and appends it back onto the new hostname.